# Synchronization Alfresco site document library to Sharepoint location

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, alfresco, alfresco-share

I have alfresco running from a server

```
      http://10.0.10.199:8080
```

and sharepoint running from port 80 i.e

```
      http://sharepoint
```

I want to synchronize everything that is on Alfresco site,

```
      http://10.0.10.199:8080/share/page/site/cnhg/
```

to a sharepoint site

```
      http://sharepoint.site.org/cnhg
```

without having to recreate the entire site on sharepoint.  I have already configured sharepoint module for Alfresco to allow online Editing using Sharepoint configuration. My alfresco version is 4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding the SharePoint protocol support that ships with Alfresco. The functionality allows you to use Microsoft Office applications to retrieve and store files in Alfresco via the SharePoint protocol. This uses Microsoft's built-in SharePoint integration but with Alfresco on the back-end instead of SharePoint.

There is currently nothing out-of-the-box that will do a sync between a SharePoint back-end and an Alfresco back-end.

There are third-party products and other open source projects that will do that sort of synchronization but nothing in the core product at the current time.